# Extract Columns based on Row data from .CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

Total Newbie with PowerShell, but used to use WSH with .vbs back in the day - so hopefully can structure this question correctly.

I would like to extract x number of columns from a .csv file, only if the row data equals a certain value - and then send the filtered data to a new .csv in another destination.

So taking a saved Windows event log as an example, I would like to extract Columns A-F but only on rows where column 'A' equals 'Error' - and then send that output to a new .csv in a child directory.

I think I am pretty close, but can only get it to save columns A-F but no rows with the data I need!

Can anyone help me figure this out or show me where I am going wrong please?

```
$folderPath = 'C:\DLA\'
$folderPathDest = 'C:\DLA\OUT\'
$desiredColumns = 'A','B','C','D','E','F'
$topics.Where({$desiredColumns.play -eq 'Error'}).topic

Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $filePath = $folderPath + $_
        $filePathdest = $folderPathDest + $_
        Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumns | Select $topics |
        Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest –NoTypeInformation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the filter directly in your pipeline:

```
Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumns | where {$_.A -eq 'Error'} | Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest –NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me to extract all the columns to a new file. This can be modified to select the desired columns:

`import-csv $filePath | ? { $_.columnName -eq 'Error' } | export-csv $filePathDest -NoTypeInformation`

columnName  is the header title of the columns